# Hive table query giving incorrect result for sum function

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hive, hdfs

Have a hive table which has data like below.

```
    select * from table1;

    id        Amount
    1         8.50
    1         -8.50
    2         3.05
```

Querying the data as below. The SUM is not returning expected output which is 0.

```
    select id, sum(amount) as sum from table1 group by id;

    id        sum
    1         -9.026113190202523E-14
    2         3.05
```

ID is of type BIGINT.
Amount is of type: Double, Column Size: 15, Decimal Digits: 15

Even if this is due to high precision of amount column why will it return a Non-Zero value. I checked the insert script of this table as well. The INSERT is happening with only two decimal places on the amount column. Strangely if I export the data to an excel and only if I sort data again in excel the sum appears as Zero. Without sort the sum shows a similar scientific value in excel.

Table is on AWS HDFS and I am using Hive to connect to it.

Comment: this is just a representation - check this: `0.0000000000001 > 9.026113190202523E-14` - this will return `True`.

Comment: Right. But It is sort of exposing a lot of errors on a bigger picture. Have lot of calculations on top of this sum function in nested selects. In one scenario I do a filter on non-zero values, join it to different sets of streaming data and export it. This is causing about 80K incorrect values to strangely appear on a extract. Have many reports/extracts like these.

Comment: well, this is how computers deal with float/double numbers. Check this in your favorite programming language: `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` - you might be surprized ;-) Usually `0.1 + 0.2` returns `0.30000000000000004` which is NOT equal to `0.3` but is very, very, very close to it

Comment: What and Where can I change to give a precise answer for my calculation? System settings etc.. Is it defined anywhere how SUM in Hive is supposed to work?

Comment: it depends on your data and your needs... What is `amount`? Would `rounding` be an option for you? If it represents "money", then i would suggest to calculate and to store everything in cents (in your currency) __as integers__ as all bankers do.

Comment: What's the output of `describe table` ? Chances are you're using either float or double for amount, which causes the floating point issues mentioned above. Use `DECIMAL` , a fixed precision format instead (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-DecimalsdecimalDecimals).  Or, like @MaxU said, use integers

Comment: ID is of type BIGINT. Amount is of type: Double, Column Size: 15, Decimal Digits: 15

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select id, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL(9,2))) sum from table1 group by id;
```

If that doesn't work try changing the column data type from double to decimal, make sure you add precision and scale i.e. `amount decimal(9,2)`

reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-DecimalsdecimalDecimals